# How can I add a prefix to titles displayed in sidebar using function.php?

Tags: filters, widgets, sidebar

What is the condition / hook to filter the titles displayed in the sidebar?

Edit: I actually meant posts titles. Like if there's a widget that displays 5 most recent posts, I want to filter the output of those 5 titles.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter widget titles by adding below filter :

```
add_filter ('widget_title', 'custom_title');
function custom_title($oldtitle) 
{
    //manipulate $title as per your need
    $title = explode(" ", $oldtitle,2);
    $titleNew = "<span>".$title[0]."</span>."$title[1];
    return $titleNew;
}
```

Comment: I actually meant posts titles. Like if there's a widget that displays 5 most recent posts, I want to filter the output of those 5 titles.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to target the *Recent Posts* widget, using the `the_title` filter, mixed with the `widget_posts_args` filter and the `loop_end` action :

```
/**
 * Recent Posts Widgets: Prepending the posts' titles
 */
add_filter( 'widget_posts_args', function( array $args )
{
    add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_prepend_post_title', 10, 2 );
    add_action( 'loop_end',  'wpse_clean_up' );
    return $args;
} );

function wpse_prepend_post_title( $title, $post_id )
{
    return 'Prefix ' . $title;   // Adjust to your needs!
} 

function wpse_clean_up( \WP_Query $q )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wpse_prepend_post_title', 10 );
}
```

[Here's](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/245949/26350) another approach using only filters.

Then you can extend the widget if you need to modify it further to your needs or create a custom shortcode.

Comment: Thanks, how do you guys find all those hooks and filters you need? For example I'd like hooks and filters for all the native widgets like pages, categories, etc. Every time I google it it either takes me forever to find it or I just don't find it at all.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/162862/how-to-get-wordpress-hook-run-sequence) can help.